# Visual Studio 2015 characters get mixed up sometimes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Sometimes when I write code the characters get mixed up. For example when I'm writing "integer", the text appears as "igetnre". Even when I try to paste some code, I have to press Ctrl+V several times in order to work.

I tried disabling Hardware Acceleration and same thing happens.

Anyone knows what's going on?

This never happened when I was using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem was Resharper 9.1.2. I updated to 9.1.3 and everything is fixed.

This is the changelog:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/07/24/resharper-9-1-3-to-the-rescue/